# Upgrading apache without upgrading Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have a server running Ubuntu 9.10, with Apache 2.2.12 being the latest available package for `apache2`.  I see, however, that 2.2.14 is available for Lucid.  Is there a way to continue using `dpkg` and get 2.2.14 (or preferably 2.2.15, since it was a [security release](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.2.15) back in March) running, or do I have to resort to a manual compile?

I would simply upgrade the OS to Lucid, but the machine sits 8 hours away and doesn't have a backup (blame management tightwads).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is get some security updates, then don't worry about it - as long as you have a standard installation and you run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

You'll get the updates from the karmic-security APT repository. It's Ubuntu's policy to not change the version of a package once released, but they will backport security updates from later releases as necessary. There are a handful of exceptions to this policy (Firefox being the most notable) but Apache2 isn't one of them.

In fact, if you look at the [apache2 karmic package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/apache2), you'll see the current version is noted as "security" and if you view the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.2.12-1ubuntu2.2/changelog) you'll see they've already backported the security issues.

If you're really interested in getting a later version without upgrading, you should read the [Ubuntu Backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) wiki page. There are a number of different options available, from re-building your own packages to using the Ubuntu backports repository to get some later packages.

Comment: Awesome!  I didn't realize that the security patches were getting backdated like that.  Unfortunately, I know our PCI scanning company is still going to complain about the version.

Answer (score 1):

Well technically you could do that by adding a `deb` line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` for lucid (here's an example) :

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe multiverse`

Then `apt-get update` and `apt-get install apache2` (to update Apache2 only). But there's absolutely NO WARRANTY AT ALL that the update won't break your Apache2 installation, or something else in the system (missing library, wrong link...).

Needless to say you shouldn't do that on a production server :)

If the update is really critical for your system, you should remove the existing package and compile Apache2 by yourself (or better, create a package using `checkinstall` which will be easily uninstallable later).